# Saving and Loading UIImage from/to string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimage, nsdata

Using the http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024 post from another question i am allowing the user to enter a signature. When the user is finished entering the signature i want to save it away to the database. I want to know if it is possible to save a UIImage to a string at all? And than also reload the UIImage from the string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to store it as a string? Doesn’t the database support some binary data format?

Comment: The accepted answer is not correct. You should not be trying to represent binary data of a PNG representations as string. The answer by namk42c should be accepted, IMHO. Or, better, zoul's comment above is cuts to the quick (namely that you shouldn't be converting it to a string at all and that you should store in in the database as a BLOB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could represent it as `NSData` and then convert it to `NSString`:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourPNGImage);
NSString *imageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [imageData bytes] length:[imageData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In case of jpeg images you can easily use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` istead of `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Answer (score 4):

You should save your `UIImage` object as a Base64 string:

1. Convert `UIImage` to `NSData` using [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)
2. Convert `NSData` to Base64 string and then save the encoded string into database.

To load the image, reverse the process.

1. Create a NSData object from saved Base64 encoded string.
2. Use `[UIImage initWithData]` to initial an `UIImage` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Imagename, 1.0f);
NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data];
```